# Adding a <code> button to the WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: wysiwyg

I've been looking for a way to add a button to wrap text in  `for the WYSIWYG editor in Wordpress 3.3.1.`

I tried this:

```
function enable_more_buttons($buttons) {
 $buttons[] = 'code';
 return $buttons;
}
add_filter("mce_buttons_3", "enable_more_buttons");
```

But that did not work as expected. It did display a button, but it brings up a popup window to edit the HTML.

In addition to  it would be nice to have  and .

Comment: With TinyMCE, "code" refers to the markup of the textbox itself.  It's *supposed* to launch a popup window to edit the HTML.  You need a way to add a custom button, because there isn't a baked-in "preformatted" feature.  I recommend asking on Stack Overflow instead, because this is TinyMCE-related, not WordPress-related, and will be closed as off-topic soon enough.

Comment: I finally found a plugin that did just what I wanted - a button for <code> in the WYSIWYG editor: WYSIWYG Inline Code Command

Comment: Please post your answer as a new Answer below and accept it so others can learn what you did.  Providing a link out to the plugin would also be useful.

Comment: Ah - sorry. Posted in the wrong textbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found a plugin that did just what I wanted - a button for  in the WYSIWYG editor: [WYSIWYG Inline Code Command](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wysiwyg-inline-code-command/)

Comment: Mark the question as _answered_ please.

Comment: Done! Thanks for reminding me. It wouldn't let me mark it when I first posted. Had to wait 24 hours - forgot.

Comment: [TinyMCE Code Button](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-code-button/) is another plugin that does the same thing. (Neither plugin seems to be actively maintained, so there's a risk that one or the other might disappear from the plugin repository at some point.)